# Selecting a fuse for a device that powers on at 48V @ 0.1 amps

Tags: fuses

I am passing current through an Ethernet cable in order to power on a device.

Basically I am making use of the Blue and Brown cables:

[image]

The device that I am powering uses 48 V DC and only uses 0.1 amps. In other words it uses only about 5 watts of power.

Anyways, I would like to add protection to the device that I am powering. I was thinking about using a fuse. How can I select a fuse that will blow up if I pass 60 V @ .1 amps for example? I have measured the current consumption and it variates between 0.07 amps and 0.14 amps. How can I select the right fuse?

When searching on the internet most of the fuses are rated at higher currents.

When I search for fuses on https://lcsc.com/products/Fuses_11022.html I have so many options and none of them have the option of selecting 48 V dc and .2 amps.

I have already built a project that measures the voltage using an Atmega 328 chip (Arduino). Can I use that to measure the voltage and if it uses more than 50 V, for example, power off the circuit using a MOSFET?  Do people do that to protect circuits?

Comment: The fuse is to protect the wire, not the load. Determine the current carrying capacity of your wire and that will dictate the fuse. Also note the fuse fails on current, not voltage. Add a varistor of the required size/ voltage to your device. If the voltage exceeds this, the varistor will cause the fuse to blow.

Comment: If you're delivering 48 volts over an ethernet cable, why not just use standard power-over-ethernet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One confusing thing about fuses is that their datasheet parameters do not directly correspond to "normal" characteristics you use to describe the device to be protected, like current and voltage.

The most important parameter is I<sup>2</sup>t, which is an energy required to melt the fuse. As you can see, lower current at a long time can blow a fuse just the same as short pulse with higher current. So, you **cannot select a fuse** by saying "I want it to blow at 0.1A", because you requirement missing a time component.

The second thing to remember is that the shape of the pulse does matter. Two pulses with same duration and same maximum current can deliver completely different energy. The typical case to consider is inrush protection, where huge initial current exponentially decreases to almost nothing. For this reason different formulas are used to calculate the required I<sup>2</sup>t rating. See for example this excellent [Fuseology Selection Guide](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/product_catalogs/littelfuse_fuseology_selection_guide.pdf.pdf) from Littelfuse. On page 7 they show the formulas for different wave shapes.

So, the above tells you when the fuse will blow. Current rating, on the other hand, tells you what current you can pass through the fuse indefinitely. Note that there are "pulse withstanding" slow-blow fuses that can survive many short pulses with much higher currents.

Finally, breaking capacity and voltage rating specify conditions in which the fuse can operate (as in "blow out") safely, without creating an arc and potentially being a hazard. This is the only time the voltage comes into the picture, by the way. In your question you mention it many times, but the fact is, it is irrelevant. Any fuse rated higher than highest possible voltage in your circuit will do.

And to answer the edited part of your question - if you want to protect your device from over-voltage then **fuses are not what you should be looking for**. But that would be a completely different question, so cannot be answered here. I recommend you to do a research on over-voltage protection and if you still have questions ask them in separate question.

Answer (score 3):

The voltage rating on fuses isn't the voltage they blow at, it's the withstand voltage. A voltage higher than the rating may arc across the fuse and prevent it breaking the circuit.

To blow with excessive voltage you will need a crowbar circuit. This will usually include a zener diode or varistor which will begin conducting when the voltage exceeds a certain threshold. That then blows the fuse.

Keep in mind that fuses blow very slowly with moderate overloads. For example if you find a 100mA fuse and you draw 150mA it may take minutes to blow, if it does at all. Only with dead shorts and other extreme overloads will the fuse blow quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the help Drew. So what do you recommend I should use to protect my device? Should I use a zener diode so that I do not exceed 48V?

Comment: That's a complicated question. It depends on what you're trying to protect, and what types of faults are likely. You should write a list of the most likely fault conditions, and then work out what will happen in each case. From there you can add protection to mitigate the damage.